# Setup AngularJS and NodeJS on Xampp Web server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm working on creating a web application that uses AngularJS's data binding tactics to create a very nice frontend based on the backend data model. However, the backend data needs to come from incoming HTTP post requests, which I've figured out I'm going to use NodeJS to handle.

Right now I'm using an Xampp local web server to do all the testing, and here is the file structure I've setup.

[setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmNGO.png)

As you can see, I've created a website directory for my website files, and when I visit `localhost/website`in my browser, the page loads the files I have. Currently, I have Angular up and running with this source code:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    <h1>{{80/5}}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

And the only text on the page is 16, as it is expected.

My question is, how can I also have a NodeJS server running at the same location (`localhost/website`) so that when HTTP requests are sent to this web URL, they are intercepted and handled by Node, which can pass the results that are processed directly to Angular to handle the frontend stuff? Can you create the Node server inside of the `script.js` file I have? And what host/port would I use to grab the incoming HTTP requests?

Comment: You should create a node server, like in this [example](https://nodejs.org/api/synopsis.html) or [this example](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/). also node should be installed, and xampp is Irrelevant here.

Comment: But how does Angular fit into this? Do I just include it in the same file with the Node server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scotty Xampp Runs based on file structure, you designate one port using it's settings and then you access folders.

To use Node JS you must install node js and in node js you can set port of your choice and then you can access your content using localhost:your port number.

To make request to server you must make a call using Angular's controller.

If you are a beginner I suggest this tutorial to you.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLX2HoWE32I8Nkzw2TqcifObuhgJZz8a0U

Check the first video of the playlist, that'll do what you want.

The playlist is for Mongodb as well if your are not using it don't refer to whole playlist. Ask me if you need more clarification.

Comment: Ahhh, this is exactly the tutorial series I needed! Thanks so much, I'm going to binge watch it now :)

Comment: If you are get stuck, let me know.